# Extend a greyscale Image to fit a RGB image

Tags: image, numpy

I need to extend an image array, that currently only holds grey-scale values in the shape of:
`(640,480)` to `(640,480,3)`. Ultimately I need to `concatenate`both - a rgb `numpy` array with the greyscale `numpy` array. 
`greyscalearray[..., np.newaxis]` results in `(640,480,1)` - is there a way I can add `np.zeros(3,1)` for the last axis?

Comment: Do you want to convert the gray array into a color array that looks gray and concatenate it next to a color image, or are you asking for a red array, like the answer gives you? In that case, why are you mentioning the concatenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
RGB = np.dstack((grey, np.zeros_like(grey), np.zeros_like(grey)))
```

The benefit of using `np.zeros_like()` is that you get an array matching the dimensions **and the `dtype`** of your single-channel, grey image without having to specify either!

So here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
grey = np.ones((64,48),dtype=np.uint8) 

print(grey.shape)      # prints (64, 48)

# Make 3-channel from singe-channel
RGB = np.dstack((grey, np.zeros_like(grey), np.zeros_like(grey))) 

print(RGB.shape)       # prints (64, 48, 3)
print(RGB[0,0])        # prints [1,0,0]
```

`np.dstack()` stacks in the **depth** axis. Its friends are `np.vstack()` which stacks **vertically** to concatenate one image **vertically below** another, and `np.hstack()` which stacks **horizontally** to concatenate one image **horizontally beside** another.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate answer. yes, I used vstack to put the images together, it works like a charm. I was not aware of dstack, but it makes absolute sense.

Comment: If you want one of the channels to be 255 instead of 0, you can just use `np.zeros_like(grey) + 255` as well. Glad it works for you - good luck with your project.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Aha, one with a sense of humour! I've been looking for you on SO for 6 years!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the joke is. I guess OP wanted a red array. Your search continues